# AFNetworking - Download File, unexpected message format 'Raw'

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlrequest

I am basically trying to download a file which can be from a PDF to a PNG. I am using AFNetworking 1.x.

However, I am getting an error:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myserver.com/webservices/Services/"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
//NSLog(@"Formatted URL: %@", formattedURL);
//NSMutableURLRequest *photoRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];

[parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:@"10772"] forKey:@"FileId"];
[parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"requireUnCompression"];
NSMutableURLRequest *fileRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"FileService.svc/DownloadFile" parameters:parameters];
//[fileRequest setHTTPBody:<#(NSData *)#>]
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:fileRequest];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successss!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@", [operation error]);
}];

[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

However, I am getting an error:

`Failed: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x12112770 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"faultType":"InvalidOperationException","message":"The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details."}, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0xc865c40> { URL: https://myserver.com/webservice/Services/FileService.svc/DownloadFile }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myserver.com/webservices/Services/FileService.svc/DownloadFile, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xc8696a0> { URL: https://myserver.com/webservices/Services/FileService.svc/DownloadFile } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 327;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 17 Oct 2013 19:45:07 GMT";
    "Persistent-Auth" = true;
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }}`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting the ParameterEncoding to `AFJSONParameterEncoding`? I am not sure if that will help you here. One of my apps downloads PDFs, but I ended up using NSURLConnection, not AFNetworking to download the PDF. I found it worked better. If you'd like I can share that code with you.

Comment: @RyanG yes, I got `ExtendedException","message":"This file is invalid."`

Comment: I just updated my comment above

Comment: @RyanG Yes, I would love that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I download PDFs/Images/WordDocs in my app without AFNetworking, I also ran into issues, so I decided to just good old NSURLConnection. My NSURLRequest does not use POST data, but I modified the NSURLRequest in here for POST data.

Once the file is done downloading, I present a QLPreviewController to display it. (this can handle displaying PDFs, images, or word docs. It requires a bit more code if youd like to see that as well)

Declare 4 properties in your .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *reportLength;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *reportConnection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *reportData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *reportURL;
```

also add `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to your delegate list

Then in the .m:

```
- (void)downloadReport:(NSString *)reqUID
{
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@GetReport.ashx?requestUID=%@&deviceUID=%@&token=%@", _globals.baseURL, reqUID, [MySingleton getDeviceID], _globals.token];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = @"FileID=10772&requireUnCompression=1";
    [req setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    _reportConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    _reportData = [NSMutableData data];
    [_reportConnection start];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_reportData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse %@: %@", [response URL], [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields]);
    _reportLength = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]];

    if(_reportLength.longLongValue == 0)
    {
        [_reportConnection cancel];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empty Report" message:@"The report you requested is empty. " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSNumber *resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[_reportData length]];
    [_reportData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was an issue downloading the attachment. Please try again." message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not Now" otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}

//when finished save in documents directory
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *dirArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    _reportURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [dirArray objectAtIndex:0], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", _currentRequestUID]];

    NSError *err;
    if ([_reportData writeToFile:_reportURL options:NSAtomicWrite error:&err] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error: %@", _reportURL);

        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"There was an issue saving the attachment. Please try again."];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else //pdf downloaded, display using QLPreviewController
    {        
        NSLog(@"Written: _reportURL: %@", _reportURL);
        QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
        previewController.delegate=self;
        previewController.dataSource=self;
        UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnCloseQLTouch:)];
        [previewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:btn, nil]];
        [self presentViewController:previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To get the QLPreviewController working first add the `<QuickLook.framework>` to your project, then add these deletages in your .h:

```
QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate
```

Here are the datasource/delegate methods needed to display the file:

```
//quicklook datasource/ delegate

- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_reportURL];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am still having an issue it seems. In the "didReceiveResponse" it's giving only a content length of 327. For the image that is supposed to be 210714.

Comment: Could you tell me how you are setting up the QLPreviewDatasource once you have the reportURL?

Comment: I added the 2 other functions you will need for the file to display.. also add the delegates in the header